# Use Bootstrap in Next.js 12 with SCSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, next.js

After upgrading Next.js to version 12 Bootstrap with SCSS isn't working anymore.

I have a `global.scss` file which gets imported in the `_app.js`. In this file I import Bootstrap and Bootstrap Icons.

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
@import '~bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css';
```

It worked perfectly, but not after upgrading to Next.js 12. Now I get an import error and I don't know how to resolve it.

```
./styles/global.scss:5:0
Module not found: Can't resolve '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/forms/data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http:/www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16'><path fill='none' stroke=''

Import trace for requested module:
./styles/global.scss
./pages/_app.jsx

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

Comment: Should be fixed by [PR#31134](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/31134) (merged). Wait for a canary release with that fix, and then you can test it out.

Comment: Validated that it works with the canary install. Now eagerly waiting for an actual patch release. Really thankful for this thread.

Answer (score 2):

This is a temporary workaround.

```
$form-check-input-checked-bg-image: none;
$form-check-radio-checked-bg-image: none;
$form-check-input-indeterminate-bg-image: none;
$form-switch-bg-image: none;
$form-switch-focus-bg-image: none;
$form-switch-checked-bg-image: none;
$form-select-indicator: none;
$form-feedback-icon-valid: none;
$form-feedback-icon-invalid: none;
$navbar-light-toggler-icon-bg: none;
$navbar-dark-toggler-icon-bg: none;
$accordion-button-icon: none;
$accordion-button-active-icon: none;
$carousel-control-prev-icon-bg: none;
$carousel-control-next-icon-bg: none;
$btn-close-bg: none;

@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
@import '~bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css';
```

Comment: Why do you see this as a temporary workaround? What are the limitations or tradeoffs of this approach that make it unsuitable as a long-term solution?

Comment: This is a temporary workaround because this bug will eventually be fixed by [31134](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/31134). Changing those variables to `none;` fixes the errors but not the bug itself.

Comment: @Cosmo that issue is now marked as resolved and closed. I guess that means we can now do as the OP suggested, without this list of none-values?

Answer (score 0):

I just got this problem myself and using Cosmo workaround, but encountered a problem when using checkbox, the tick icon is missing. to fix this, you can copy the image from bootstrap _variables.scss url("you copy this text") to a new file and save it as svg.

and change Cosmo workaround from none to this new svg path.

**_variables.scss**

```
$form-check-input-checked-bg-image:       url("copy this text here") !default;
```

**new_svg.svg**

```
paste the text here and save
```

**global.scss**

```
$form-check-input-checked-bg-image: url("path/to/new/new_svg.svg");
```

> note: you might need to use '../../../' to your path, because it look for the file from bootstrap node_modules folder